# How does Maven handle WAR dependencies at compile time?

Tags: rest, maven, war, dependency-management

I'm using Maven 3 to handle a (large) project. This project defines a set of REST services, using Scala, Akka and the Spray framework. Each service is defined as an independent project, producing a WAR thanks to the "mvn package" command.

I have to "assemble" these different services into a "system", that is, a subset of these services to be deployed for a given purpose, in a single WAR. Maven WAR overlay works good as a first impression: simply create a new project, and add the services to be included as dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.modelbased.sensapp.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>net.modelbased.sensapp.service.metamodel.repository</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>     
</dependencies>
```

It works well, and the classes contained in the independent services are included in the final WAR.

```
jar tf target/net.modelbased.sensapp.system.envision-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war 
[...]
WEB-INF/classes/net/modelbased/sensapp/service/metamodel/repository/ModelLister.class
[...]
```

But ... The Spray framework requires the implementation of a bootstrap, that is, a class that load the implemented services. This file has to be compiled, as it is a plain scala class. But it looks like maven did not includes the WAR dependencies in the compilation classpath.

I saw the WARpath plugin (http://static.appfuse.org/maven-warpath-plugin/) ... But It does not look more or less outdated. Is there a "standard" way of doing what I'd like to do (i.e., include a WAr in the compilation classpath).

Ps. One of the requirement of the project is that each service MUST be deployable as an independent artifact. A solution could be to implement the core of the service as a JAR project, and also provide a WAR project that includes a refarence to the JAR and the associated config file. But it will multiply by 2 the number of project defined, which is not optimal in a way ...

Answer (score 0):

The solution you propose looks good.

You can build a jar from your classes, and then build a war using this jar as a dependency.

You probably can also do this in one single project, I can see no need for two different projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the configuration of the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) which offers you a way to create a separate jar file out of the files from src/main/java.
You have to add the configuration items:

```
  <configuration>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  </configuration>
```

This will create a separate jar file with the classifier **classes** which can be used as a usual dependency.